# How to click the attribute link

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to click the src link of the video file using jwplayer, i managed to print the link and it's exactly the result i want but i don't know how to click it
Here's the html 
https://gyazo.com/ae290fad0c8af99756cf8976a939bfae

I have try adding `.get_attribute("src")` in find_element and it doesn't work

from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('my website')
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mediaplayer"]/div[2]/div[3]/video')

for link in elem:
    print(link.get_attribute('src'))
```

Comment: Is this a button? If so, you need to use the `click()` method. If it's a hyperlink, Then the `src` is the URL that you need to go to

Comment: It's a google videoplayback URL

Comment: I don't think you mean click it... I think you mean navigate to the URL extracted from the `src` attribute of the video.

Comment: Thanks you i have found the solution i didn't know it mean navigate @JeffC